# Couldn't find User with 'id'=number in show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many users and every users have cases. When I try to open the show page of the case it give me this error Couldn't find User with 'id'=4 in http://localhost:3000/cases/4
Here is my codes
in the routes

```
resources :cases
```

in case model

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

in user model

```
 has_many :cases
```

in case controller

```
class CasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!,except: [:index,:show]
  before_action :find_case ,only:[:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]

  def new
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @case = @user.cases.build
  end
  def index
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @cases=@user.cases
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @case = @user.cases.build(case_params)
    if @case.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(:id => @user.id)
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update

    if @case.update(case_params)
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "case Information updated successfully"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Couldn't update!"
      render :edit
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @case.destroy
    redirect_to doctors_path, notice: "case deleted Successfully"
  end 

private

  def find_case
    @case = Case.find(params[:id])
  end

  def case_params
    params.require(:case).permit(:pt_name,:date_received,:due_date,:shade,:mould,:upper_lower,{step_ids: []})
  end
end
```

in case show.html.erb

```
  <strong>Case Id: </strong> <%= @case.id %><br>
  <strong>For doctor: </strong> <%= current_user.first_name.capitalize %><br>
  <strong>Patient Name: </strong> <%= @case.pt_name.capitalize %><br>
  <strong>Date Received: </strong><%= @case.date_received %><br>
  <strong>Due Date: </strong><%= @case.due_date  %><br>
  <strong>Shade: </strong><%= @case.shade %><br>
  <strong>Mould: </strong><%= @case.mould %><br>
  <strong>Upper or Lowe: </strong><%= @case.upper_lower %><br>
  <%= link_to :controller => :cases, :action => :edit, :id => @user.id do %>
  edit
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in `CasesController` & finding case using `params[:id]` in `find_case` method.
You also finding user using same `params[:id]` in `show` method.

If you want `user` which is associated to the `case` you can change the code to find user in `show` method & other methods like following.

```
@user = @case.user
```

Note :- As you said in your question users have cases you case model should be

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```